# Unable to retrieve data from .Net webservice

Tags: vb.net, web-services, vb.net-2010, webservice-client

I am trying to consume one third party .Net web service in my vb.net project. 
In Config file, I have set the Authentication mode as Windows

When I am Writing below Code

```
Dim proclaimService As New ProclaimWebService.ProclaimService
proclaimService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
myObject = proclaimService.ProClaim_Get_Exclusions(sSQL)
```

I am getting below error

> "Client found response content type of 'text/html', but expected
>   'text/xml'. The request failed with the error message: -- The page
>   cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
>   --."

For the below code

> Dim proclaimService As New ProclaimWebService.ProclaimService myObject
>   = proclaimService.ProClaim_Get_Exclusions(sSQL)

I am getting below error

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized."

What part I am missing here?? I dont have much knowledge as am new to the Web Service..

Comment: are you sure your windows credentials have access to the service?looks like you will need username and password along with domain details to access it

Comment: @Arpit It is correct ?? I am writing below line "proclaimService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials". It will find default credentials and sent it to web service...

Comment: from the first exception,it does look like you are able to hit the service.The reason of getting "Client found response content type of 'text/html', but expected 'text/xml" error is that your service is throwing some exception and sending you a error page (yellow page which comes in .net in case of an unhandled exception).Try to check that the method you are consuming is really working and giving correct results.

Comment: @Arpit I dont have access to check web service code as its hosted in other server.... As per your comment, you meant that error is coming from web service.. i'm i correct??? or there's an error in my code while consuming web service?

Comment: As of now it looks that the hosted service method has problem.Can you check the inner-exception object and see if there is any detail there?

Comment: @Arpit : Thanks.. Issue is resolved now. There was some problem from web service end as you mentioned.